# post method of class based view is not working.while get method is responding.form is launched using get method but post is not

Tags: django-forms, django-class-based-views

Here checkout form open but problem is data entered do not save in database. I have used post method in checkout.html and model of form is created in database. But data put by user do not save in database.

views.py

```
 class CheckoutView(View):

    def get(self,*args,**kwargs):
        form = CheckoutForm()
        context = {
             'form': form
        }
        print("get is working")
        return render(self.request,"checkout.html",context)

    def post(self,*args,**kwargs):
        form = CheckoutForm(self.request.POST or None)
        print("Now post is also working")
        #NOT WORKING
        if form.is_valid():
            street_address = form.cleaned_data.get('street_address')
            apartment_address = form.cleaned_data.get('apartment_address')
            country = form.cleaned_data.get('country')
            zip = form.cleaned_data.get('zip')
            billing_address = BillingAddress(
                user = self.request.user,
                street_address = street_address,
                apartment_address = apartment_address,
                country = country,
                zip = zip
            )
            billing_address.save()
            return redirect('core:checkout')
        messages.warning(self.request,"failed checkout")
        return redirect('core:checkout')
```

Comment: Have you checked the output of form.is_valid()

Comment: Sir not even print mentioned just after post method.

Comment: Print just after the post method is not responding. I think problem lies in calling of post method.